# Why is string.Substring(length,0) allowed?

Tags: c#, string

Can somebody tell me for what is allowed to use `string.Substring(someIndex,0)`?

```
string a = "abc";
var result = a.Substring(1,0);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This code will be compiled and will write nothing to console.
What is the reason that this is allowed?
In which case can this be used?

UPDATE

I will clarify that I know what is this method and that in this case it is returning empty string. I am NOT asking why the result is empty. I am asking why it's allowed to do this.

Comment: I do not see a reason not to allow it. You do not always know in advance what the length will be since it can be the result of a (complex) formula.

Comment: Why is it allowed?  Why _wouldn't_ it be allowed?  The returned value of an empty string is correct -- an exception would simply make simple code more complex with extra guards for no good reason.

Comment: You are complaining that "this code will be compiled" -- so, what did you expect? Would you rather complicate the compiler by instilling specific knowledge in it of `String.Substring()` and of the fact that a zero literal argument is meaningless?  The compiler does not know what `String.Substring()` is or does, and besides, there exist analysis tools for that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This code will be compiled and will write nothing to console.

First of all *technically speaking*, this statement is wrong: it writes a new line to the console. Thats where the `Line` in `WriteLine` comes in. But let's not be picky.

> What is the reason that this is allowed?

There is no reason to *disable* it. Say for instance you want to make a *string insertion* method:

```
public static string StringInsert(String original, String toInsert, int index) {
    return original.Substring(0,index)+toInsert+original.SubString(index);
}
```

Now our `StringInsert` method cannot know whether or first or second part will be empty (we could decide to insert at index `0`). If we had to take into account that the first substring could have zero length, or the second, or both, then we would have to implement a lot of `if`-logic. Now we can use a *one liner*.

Usually one considers a string *s* a *sequence* of characters *s=s<sub>0</sub>s<sub>1</sub>...s<sub>n-1</sub>*. A substring from *i* with length *j*, is the string *t=s<sub>i</sub>s<sub>i+1</sub>...s<sub>i+j-1</sub>*. There is no ambiguity here: it is clear that if *j* is 0, then the result is the empty string. Usually you only raise an exception if something is *exceptional*: the input does not make any sense, or is not allowed.

Answer (score 6):

Many things are allowed because there is no good reason to prohibit them.

Substrings of length zero are one such thing: in situations when the desired length is computed, this saves programmers who use your library from having to zero-check the length before making a call.

For example, let's say the task is to find a substring between the first and the last hash mark `#` in a string. Current library lets you do this:

```
var s = "aaa#bbb"; // <<== Only one # here
var start = s.IndexOf('#');
var end = s.LastIndexOf('#');
var len = end-start;
var substr = s.Substring(start, len); // Zero length
```

If zero length were prohibited, you would be forced to add a conditional:

```
var len = end-start;
var substr = len != 0 ? s.Substring(start, len) : "";
```

Checking fewer pre-requisites makes your library easier to use. In a way, Pythagorean theorem is useful in no small part because it works for the degenerate case, when the length of all three sides is zero.

Answer (score 2):

The method you use has the following signature:

```
public string Substring(
    int startIndex,
    int length
)
```

where `startIndex` is

> The zero-based starting character position of a substring in this
>   instance.

and `length` is

> The number of characters in the substring.

That being said the following call is a pretty valid call

```
var result = a.Substring(1,0);
```

but is meaningless, since the number of charcaters in the substring you want to create is 0. This is why you don't get anything in the Console as an output.

Apparently, a call of `Substring` with passing the value of 0 as the value of second argument has no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx):

> public string Substring(startIndex, length)
>
> A string that is equivalent to the substring of length length that
> begins at startIndex in this instance, or Empty if startIndex is equal
> to the length of this instance and length is zero.

Basically, when you do `someString.Substring(n, 0);`, what you're getting back is a string that starts at `n` and has length 0.

> The length parameter represents the total number of characters to extract from the current string instance.

Thats why nothing is printed to the console. The returned string is empty (has length 0).

EDIT:

Well, there is a limitation in place: the method throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if:

> startIndex plus length indicates a position not within this instance.
>
> -or-
>
> startIndex or length is less than zero.

The reason they made the exception be thrown if `length` is *less* than zero and not if it is *equal* is most likely because, though pointless in **most** situations, requesting a string of 0 length is not an invalid request.

Comment: @S.Petrosov edited